# Enable a gameObject that is present in another scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I set a gameObject true/false `GameObject.SetActive(true);` that is present in another scene while I do the above through a script from my current scene?

Comment: If that scene is not loaded at the time you cant.

Comment: @Eddge then how about accessing script that is present in another scene?

Comment: if the scene is not loaded you can't,  the GameObjects only get loaded if the scene is loaded, the scripts in that scene on those GameObjects only get loaded if the GameObject they are attached to are loaded.

Comment: Take a look ae making a GameObject with a singleton pattern or using "DontDestroyOnLoad"  So that object is persistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Eddge said, **you can't access objects from scenes that aren't loaded.**
Scene objects are actually created when the scene is loaded, so it's not possible to access them before.

The problem being, when the new scene is loaded, the old scene (with the script that wanted to call `SetActive` in your case) has been unloaded.

## DontDestroyOnLoad

> Do not destroy the target Object when loading a new Scene.
>   The load of a new Scene destroys all current Scene objects. Call `Object.DontDestroyOnLoad` to preserve an Object during level loading.

-- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

This is suitable if having an object from your current scene persist in the loaded scene helps solving your issue.

## LoadScene additively

For cases when `DontDestroyOnLoad` doesn't cut it, it's possible to load your new scene without unloading the old one, giving you a chance to pass information between the two.

*(this is actually what DontDestroyOnLoad does, as it puts the target object into a "scene" called DontDestroyOnLoad, that never gets unloaded)*

You can use `SceneManagement.LoadScene` with the mode `LoadSceneMode.Additive` to achieve that. Be aware that both scenes will be active at the same time until you unload the first one!

See [LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html), [LoadSceneAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) and [UnloadSceneAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync.html).

## Statics

You can also simply store data in static fields, which are kept throughout your app's lifetime, to retain data and references across scenes.
That might be a simpler solution to pass a few primitive types, but remember that they are *globals*, and thus suffer the same drawbacks.

See [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

There is a hacky way I just found out recently, scriptable objects will also work fine if you want to send data from scene to scene because scriptable is saved as an asset in the project so it is independent of the scene. Just create a scriptable object, then you can update your data from one scene and access them from another scene.

**Example Code:**

Simply create a scriptable object code:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "StoreData")]
public class StoreData : ScriptableObject {
    public bool objectActive;
}
```

Then access your scriptable object in the first scene and set your boolean in the scriptable object to true:

```
public class FirstSceneClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public StoreData storeData;
    public SetObjectActive() {
       storeData.objectActive = true;
    }
}
```

Then when you change your scene you can access your scriptable object again and set your gameObject to be active or not based on the boolean:

```
public class SecondSceneClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public StoreData storeData;
    void Start() {
        if (storeData.objectActive) {
           // Set your game object active here
        }
    }
}
```