# Need clarification on singletons + game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton

I'm still a bit lost on this. Basically I want to have a persistent gameobject throughout multiple scenes. This gameobject will represent the players avatar. It is displayed using a prefab.

I tried adding the singleton script to my login scene controller. I have a `public GameObject` class parameter but it isn't showing up in the inspector so I can drop the prefab in. Maybe I'm getting this wrong.

Also, let's say I'm testing a scene. Since the singleton is initialized in the login scene, How would I get this global gameobject prefab into that new scene I'm testing considering I won't even be loading the login scene during testing?

I think I'm just super confused. All I want is to be able to use 1 script which represents the players "avatar", including the prefab used to display it, and have it persist throughout the entire game. Is this possible? Also, how do I get it when I'm testing scenes and haven't called the scene containing the singleton?

Thanks for anyone who can help me.

Comment: I think the "easiest" way would be to create a test-scene with just your avatar in it, set it up for testing, and load the scene additively in the editor (either just drag that scene into the hierarchy or use the context menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I want to have a persistent gameobject throughout multiple scenes. This gameobject will represent the players avatar.

Use [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) on the object that should persist throughout multiple scenes.
Take caution if you are loading back the same scene that set the Object to `DontDestroyOnLoad`, as it will create another same object that has a `DontDestroyOnLoad`. <s>[This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/709258/dontdestroyonload-only-sometimes.html) post talks about it.</s>
**Edit** (Thanks to [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219084/yes)), check the comments in this answer.

(There are also a few more options that you have depending on your needs, Hugo's answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274716/enable-a-gameobject-that-is-present-in-another-scene-in-unity/57275921#57275921) post has it.)

> I tried adding the singleton script to my login scene controller. I have a public GameObject class parameter but it isn't showing up in the inspector so I can drop the prefab in. Maybe I'm getting this wrong.

Show some codes? It is hard to exactly tell what is wrong.
It might be the fact that you forgot to drag in your script to a game-object, or the class is static, etc.

Comment: Thats a quite old post, we now have the awesome `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod` which allows to do something before anything else happens. And its scene independent, it just needs to exist. The problem with OPs post tho is to get the Avatar loaded, ofc you could do Resources.Load, but does he want to do that in the build aswell? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute-ctor.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeLoadType.html

Comment: @yes right, I never noticed there was such a useful attribute, thanks for bringing light to it :v

Comment: There is a simlar one for the editor aswell `InitializeOnLoad` https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html